# How to continue to consume a memory after "MemoryError" was caught

Tags: linux, python-2.7, out-of-memory

I'm developing a tool for a stress testing. Its purpose is to consume all free memory. My problem is to constantly eat all free memory even if some amount of it was freed during script execution and especially after MemoryError was caught.

I tried to handle "MemoryError" exception with pass or continue statements, but it won't help. If MemoryError occurs script doesn't consume newly freed memory. Maybe it happens due to some OS limitations.

```
def mem_cons(x):
timestamp()
a = []
idx = 0
appender = a.append
MEGA_STR = 'F' * (10 ** 4 * x)
try:
    while True:
        try:
            idx += 1
            if idx > 10000:
                if 'kill' in flag:
                    print("")
                    timestamp()
                    print("Memory consumption was remotely stopped.\nPlease use \'ctrl+c\' command to exit")
                    a = []
                    timestamp()
                    print("Memory was cleared")
                    break
                idx = 0
            appender(MEGA_STR)
        except MemoryError:
            continue
            timestamp()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("")
    timestamp()
    print("Program has been stopped")
```

**Scenario:**

- Script eats memory from 20% to 100%
- MemoryException was caught
- Some memory was freed manually lets say - 5.1%

**Actual result:**

After that entire memory consumption level is still at 94.9% and doesn't growing (as we can see at [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1Ymu.png) - after the red line)

**Expected result:**

Script continues to consume manually freed memory and holds its level at 100% after MemoryException was caught.

**Thanks in advance!**